# Can I use a class level typedef as template argument for the base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef

Assume a templated base class:

```
template<typename T>class BaseClass;
```

In other classes I want to inherit from this, where `T` is a rather complicated type, so I would like to use a `typedef`. Because I do not want to pollute the namespace I want to have the `typedef` inside the class definition:

```
class ChildClass : public BaseClass<MyVeryVeryVeryComplicatedType> {
  typedef MyVeryVeryComplicatedType LocalType;
  ...
}
```

Now of course I cannot yet use `LocalType` as the template argument for `BaseClass` and have to write the complicated definition (`MyVeryVeryComplicatedType`) twice. (So the answer to the title question is 'No', I guess.)

**Question:** Is there any way to only have the definition only once but still only defined inside the class (or in a similar way that limits the scope of `LocalType`)?

Note: I thought about using a macro, but noticed that the result would be the same (or even worse) as having the `typedef` before the class definition.

**Edit:** For clarification: I have a base class because I want to want to have several different children which share some functionality. The shared parts only need to know that there is some type `T`. Since the details of the types used in the child classes have nothing to do with the shared functionalities I think that the base class should not know of these details (in practice, I would have to put a lot of `#include` statements into the base class to be able to define the `typedef`s for all child classes). Each child class has a rather different `MyVeryVeryVeryComplicatedType`.

Comment: I think there's no way to have your `typedef` defined in the `class` and then address it outside with no class qualification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define it in the base class:

```
template <typename T> class BaseClass {
protected:
    typedef T LocalType;

    // whatever else
};

class ChildClass : public BaseClass<MyVeryVeryVeryComplicatedType> {
    // LocalType is usable here, and aliases MyVeryVeryVeryComplicatedType
};
```

Comment: The base class should be rather abstract and not know of the complicated implementation specific type(s). It would maybe also not make too much sense to have the base class templated otherwise. Sorry for not pointing that out clearly.

Comment: @user2296653: It doesn't need to know anything about the complicated type. It only need to know its template parameter, provided by the derived class.

Comment: @user2296653: See my update, which makes it clearer that `T` refers to the template parameter, not the complicated type name.

Comment: Ah, I really did not understand it correctly before. Thank's for the edit. Nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a little helper namespace:

```
namespace ChildClassNamespace {
    typedef MyVeryVeryComplicatedType LocalType;
    class ChildClass : public BaseClass<LocalType> { /* ... */ };
}
using ChildClassNamespace::ChildClass;
```

Comment: This certainly is a way, but not ideal, because with your solution I would have to either write the using statement whenever I want to use the class, or have it in the header file of the ChildClass which would have the same effect as a typedef outside the class. I do not want to write the using statements whenever I use the class, because the typedef is only relevant to private class features. (Sorry for not pointing that out.)

Answer (score 3):

No. Put the `typedef` in the enclosing namespace.

That makes the most sense *anyway*, since you're using it in two of that namespace's types (`ChildClass` and `BaseClass<LocalType>`).

Comment: No, I use the type T only in an abstract way in the base class. Details of MyVeryVeryComplicatedType are only used by the child class.

Comment: @user2296653: You use it _enough_ in the base class, otherwise you wouldn't need to pass it down as a template argument.